# Java compiling error netbeans

Tags: java

This is an error am getting when compiling my project on netbeans:

```
Exception while loading the app : java.lang.Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException:   
ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException:  
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.ClassCastException:
core.smd.classes.FormData   
cannot be cast to javax.servlet.Servlet

D:\Users\GHAMKS1C\Documents\NetBeansProjects\SMDApp\nbproject\build-impl.xml:728: 
The module has not been deployed.
at org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.deployment.devmodules.api.Deployment.deploy 
  (Deployment.java:210)
at org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.ant.Deploy.execute(Deploy.java:106)
at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor45.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
```

Any idea?
Thanks

Comment: Are we supposed to guess without seeing the code?

Comment: well it was working for all classes and i was able to launch the site..not sure what happened. so I thought it was simple to figure out as it may be a common error in build xml :(

Comment: `core.smd.classes.FormData cannot be cast to javax.servlet.Servlet`.. I think you should check your code again. There is this wrong casting somewhere. Usually, you will see `Caused by:` in the error. This should show you the exact reason.

Answer (score 0):

The exception says `core.smd.classes.FormData cannot be cast to javax.servlet.Servlet`. So I presume you're using the FormData class somewhere where a Servlet should be used. Perhaps you have misconfigured your web.xml.

Comment: ok should I post it here? because am unsure...i hardly touched anything :(

Answer (score 0):

OK got it:
In netbeans under servlets, in the servlet class, I had a wrong value. The correct generic value that is there by default is:

javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet

I had to recreate the project, but that's the only difference between new and old. Hence it is cause of problem.

Hope this helps someone in future :)